# Add an Accept and Decline Button on every Row

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to add a button on every row which I already did. When I click update which updates a certain field on the database it doesn't work. When the button is clicked it's redirected to the approve.php file.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","rabco");// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM service_request");


                    echo "<table border='1'>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Service ID</th>
                    <th>Service Type</th>
                    <th>Schuduled Date</th>
                    <th>Scheduled Time</th>
                    <th>Client Reference
                    <th>Client ID</th>
                    <th>Admin ID</th>
                    <th>Special Instructions</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Approve</th>
                    <th>Decline</th>
                    </tr>";

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Service_ID'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Service_type'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Sched_date'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Sched_time'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Client_reference'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Client_IDN'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Admin_IDN'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Special_instructions'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Request_status'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td><form action='approve.php' method='POST'>        <input type='hidden' name='accept' value='".$row["Service_ID"]."'/><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Approve'/></form></td>";
                    echo "<td><form action='decline.php' method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='decline' value='".$row["Service_ID"]."'/><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Decline'/></form></td>";
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</table>";

                    mysqli_close($con);
                ?>



approve.php
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "rabco");
if(isset($_GET["Service_ID"]))
{ 
$row_sr=$_GET["Service_ID"];
$sql="UPDATE service_request SET Request_status = 'Approved', Admin_IDN =     '$_SESSION[Admin_ID]', Paid = 'Php 17,500', Balance = 'Php 32,500', Total_price     = 'Php 50,000' WHERE Service_ID = '$row_sr'";
$result=mysqli_query($sql);
mysqli_query($link,$result);
if($result==1)
{
header('location: adminpage-sr.php');
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using method POST on your main file but in approve php you use $_GET ??

according to your approve.php file, you can change your button to :

```
"<td><a href='approve.php?Service_ID='.$row["Service_ID"].">Approve</a></td>"
```

Comment: Still no luck Sir. :(((

Comment: are you changing the button or changing the approve.php ?
if you dont want change the button, just change all $_GET["Service_ID"] in your approve.php to $_POST["Service_ID"] , I think that will work

Comment: I was able to get it working, but the session was gone.

Comment: I have a $_SESSION['Admin_ID'] in approve.php

Comment: you forget session_start() in your approve.php

Comment: Thanks Sir, but when I add a decline.php it does no appear in the table

Comment: whats no appear ? the button of decline ? check your table code again, maybe you miss something